# jQuery load the next elements before the 3 elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found this on stack overflow.

But now I want to load the next 10 elements **before** the 3 elements.

But to get there no matter how I get it done.

jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/6FzSb/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
size_li = $("#myList li").size();
x=3;
$('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
$('#loadMore').click(function () {
    x= (x+5 <= size_li) ? x+5 : size_li;
    $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
     $('#showLess').show();
    if(x == size_li){
        $('#loadMore').hide();
    }
});
$('#showLess').click(function () {
    x=(x-5<0) ? 3 : x-5;
    $('#myList li').not(':lt('+x+')').hide();
    $('#loadMore').show();
     $('#showLess').show();
    if(x == 3){
        $('#showLess').hide();
    }
});
});
```

Who can help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: Is your main goal to append/prepend list items onto a webpage with javascript? If so I could give you a way easier and quicker solution to this. Let me know.

Comment: All you are doing is showing and hiding, so the li elements will remain in their current order. You may want to consider using that ul as a source (array-ish source?) from which to get the next group of 3 elements, and then `.prepend()` them to the visible DIV.

Comment: you are doing show hide only ... how are planning to the up / down?

Comment: If there is another solution I'd like to hear it. 
So I want to show elements before the 3 elements.